# ReactiveMongo: How to use the $in operator with _id

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo

Let's suppose we need to find a user whose id is `5546329b470000850084a622`:

```
val selector = Json.parse("""{"_id":{"$oid":"5546329b470000850084a622"}}""")

users.find(selector).map {
  ...
}
```

The equivalent from the Mongo shell would be

```
db.users.find( {_id: ObjectId("5546329b470000850084a622") } )
```

Now let's suppose we need to find the users whose ids are `5546329b470000850084a622`, `5546329b470000850084a623`, and `5546329b470000850084a624`... this is the command from the Mongo shell:

```
db.users.find( {_id: {$in: [ObjectId("5546329b470000850084a622"), ObjectId("5546329b470000850084a623), ObjectId("5546329b470000850084a624)"]}})
```

What is the equivalent JSON for ReactiveMongo? This one?

```
{
  "_id" : {
    "$oid" : {
      "$in" : [ "5546329b470000850084a622", "5546329b470000850084a623", "5546329b470000850084a624" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{"$oid":"5546329b470000850084a622"}` is the JSON representation of the same thing as `ObjectId("5546329b470000850084a622")` in the `mongo` shell. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid

I don't know [reactivemongo](/questions/tagged/reactivemongo), but this *should* work AFAIK:

```
{
  "_id" : {
      "$in" : [ {"$oid": "5546329b470000850084a622"},
                {"$oid": "5546329b470000850084a623"},
                {"$oid": "5546329b470000850084a624"} ]
  }
}
```